# Get the soundName by soundID to assign it to a UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have a `UILocalNotification`, and I don't want to set it to use a default tone. I have used AudioToolbox.framework, and I have a `SystemSoundID` by referring to this library: https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary.

But `UILocalNotification` needs a sound *name*. How can I get the name from the `SystemSoundID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Description of [soundName in UILocalNotification Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/soundName) mentions

> For this property, specify the filename (including extension) of a
>   sound resource in the app’s main bundle or
>   UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system
>   sound.

So if you want the default local notification sound use `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`.

Also, a note from [Multimedia Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW1)

> **Note:** System-supplied alert sounds and system-supplied user-interface
>   sound effects are not available to your application.

So you cannot use **any** system sound id you find in [iOSSystemSoundsLibrary](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) for this.

If you want a custom sound, you'll have to provide your own.